# After enter, excel shows wrong value of percentage

Tags: excel, cell, percentage

How can I solve the issue with entering the value in excel? The problem is that I try to enter the percentage in the cell of excel, for example 22.5, and after how I press enter for continue editing, 2250.0% appear in ceil.

I checked the region settings and everything seams ok and correct. I tried to totally reinstall Office pack, and didn't help as well.

That problem happens only in one cell, but there is no any formulas or macros... If I try to open same document on another PC, It works as expected... then I tried to make same configurations, but no changes any way ....

Please, help me find the rout cause ...

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the formatting of 22.5 to percent-notation (Ctrl+Shift+%), it'll turn into 2250%

If you then select the cell and just type 22.5, it'll get rounded up to 23% (depending on the decimals you have shown of course)

However, if you then use F2 to edit the cell by Ctrl+A and typing 22.5, it'll turn back to 2250%

As far as I know, that's due to overwriting the % as well as the number with Ctrl+A since you'll notice the % remaining when simply typing 22.5 in an already formatted cell.

So the solution is to either have the cell formatted prior to entering your value, or to "write over" your value with 22.5 (after formatting). Formulas will have to be entered with the value divided by 100 however as you will get to the unwanted 2250 again otherwise, i.e. `=A2/2` with A2 = 100 will give 5000%
This is more explained [in the documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/format-numbers-as-percentages-de49167b-d603-4450-bcaa-31fba6c7b6b4#__toc303956859)

Answer (score 0):

A percentage is a fraction of 100, so 100% will be 1 (or 100/100).
22.5 equals to 2250% since it would be expressed as 22.5*100.
To get 25% You have to put in the value 0.25.

Comment: it is not a solution... I need the solution for when I put 22.5, it remain 22.5% but not in 2250%... for me it is clear, that I need to enter 0.225 for receive 22,5% value in cell, but for other people it is additional time for calculate in mind, what value they have to put for receive the correct one..... they will not accept this....

Comment: @АртёмОрёл Then just apply this custom format: 0,00"%"